Why is the cohomology group of a coherent sheaf a complex vector space?
Let $X$ be a complex analytic  space and ${F}$  a coherent sheaf on $X$. A priori, the sheaf cohomology $H^k(X, F)$ is a group (or say a $Z$-module)
But a well-known fact tells us  that $H^k(X, F)$  is a finite dimensional complex vector space when $X$ being compact (and possibly reduced). So I guess $H^k(Y, G)$  is a  complex vector space for any  complex analytic  space $Y$ and any coherent sheaf $G$  on it.
Question: Why is $H^k(Y, G)$   a  complex vector space?  Can some one recommond a reference for this?

Coherence is irrelevant here. If $F$ is a sheaf of $K$-vector spaces on any topological space then cohomology of $F$ is again a $K$-vector space. To prove it, just use the definition.

@MoisheKohan  Thank you. So, for any $\mathcal{O}_X$-module sheaf $F$, it can be considered as a sheaf of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces, where $\mathbb{C}$ acts on $F$ via the map $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ (which acts on $F$). Is this what you meant? Can I interpret your answer in this way? Thank you.

Exactly.........
